# Finite-codimension ideal in profinite Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, profinite-groups

Given a profinite group, it is well-known that any finite-index subgroup contains a finite-index normal subgroup, namely its core.

Does anything similar hold for profinite Lie algebras? More specifically, is it true  that a finite-codimension Lie subalgebra contains a finite-codimension ideal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275183/subalgebras-with-finite-codimension). Perhaps the references are also on profinite Lie algebras.

Comment: What exactly is a profinite Lie algebra?

Comment: This is true in arbitrary groups. Why specify to profinite groups? Then the question makes sense for arbitrary Lie algebras.